# In the Flutter Isar database, How to check database schema is empty or not?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, is-empty, flutter-isar

In ObjectBox database, we can check box is empty or not, using box.isEmpty() method. Likewise how to check Isar database schema is empty or not. Because In my app I have a scenario, only data insert into the database if it's empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Schema named `Client`. You can check if the `Client` collection is empty by getting the count for the schema:

```
final isar = await Isar.open([ClientSchema]);
final count = await isar.clients.count();
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the total number of objects in this collection. For non-web
> apps, this method is extremely fast and independent of the number of
> objects in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to do this but this works (this will load all entries so if it is large then this approach is not very efficient):

```
db = await Isar.open([DrawSchema], directory: dbPath);

{Your stuff happens here}

final isEmpty = (await db.draws.where().findAll()).length==0;
```

YMMV